# swift coding, understand and better improve my code using class and swift initializer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

On my Xcode Project I have create a class (example) a class model describing a Car.

This class is the following:

example:

```
class CarModel{
    var nameOFCar: String
    var modelOfCar: String
    
    init(nameCar: String, modelCar: String) {
        self.nameOFCar = nameCar
        self.modelOfCar = modelCar
    }
}
```

I use this class on my project to develop my app, now for some reason I decide to extend the property of this CarModel I want to add a new var called "color"

if I add this var on my model I'm getting (correctly) a lot of warning around my Xcode project reporting Missing argument for parameter 'color' in call .

I'm quite new in swift and programming in general, I'm try to understand what is the best way if at certain point of my app I decide to add more details to an object.

i have created an app that manage a football team, every team have players and every player have a Model describe them with many var inside.
I want to add new function to the app, but this require me to add some extra var to the Player Model.

Do I need to go through all my project to fix all the error , or there is some better way to do it?? I have try with the extension of the class .. but not working.

thanks for spending some time to clear my mind

Comment: "Do I need to go through all my project to fix all the error?" Yes, if you want to give all your cars a different colour. This is why you should plan before you write code, and write your code in a future-proof way.

Comment: You could have a default color for the car `init(nameCar: String, modelCar: String, color: Color = Color.red) {` then all the existing calls to init will work, another option is to make the color property optional. But are either of these 2 options what you want like making all cars red by default, most likely you will have to go through all of your code and change the init to make your app behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First start with a **struct** instead of a class, one benefit is you get the initializer for free.

And avoid redundant naming, if `Car` appears in the name of the struct omit it in the properties which are called *members* in a struct

```
struct Car {
    var name: String
    var model: String
}
```

If the values of the members will never change declare them even as constants

```
struct Car {
    let name: String
    let model: String
}
```

You can add more members without changing anything.

A class is only useful if you need reference semantics.

Comment: If OP adds a (non-optional) color property to the struct then all existing calls to the Car init will generate compiler error, isn't that what the question is about?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Well the init calls must be updated anyway, declaring a property as optional just to avoid that is pretty bad practice.